# Count various entrys in a DataFrame

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pandas, dataframe

I want to find out how many different devices are in this list?
Is this sufficient for my SQL statement or do I have to do more for it.

Unfortunately, I do not know with such a large amount of data, which method is right and if the solution is right.

**Some devices come in more than once. That is, line number not = number of devices**

Suggestions as Python or as SQL are welcome

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection
from IPython.display import display


disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///gender-train-devices.db')

phones = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT device_id, COUNT(device_id) FROM phone_brand_device_model GROUP BY [device_id]', disk_engine)

print phones
```

the output is:

```
    device_id  COUNT(device_id)
0      -9223321966609553846                 1
1      -9223067244542181226                 1
2      -9223042152723782980                 1
3      -9222956879900151005                 1
4      -9222896629442493034                 1
5      -9222894989445037972                 1
6      -9222894319703307262                 1
7      -9222754701995937853                 1
8      -9222661944218806987                 1
9      -9222399302879214035                 1
10     -9222352239947207574                 1
11     -9222173362545970626                 1
12     -9221825537663503111                 1
13     -9221768839350705746                 1
14     -9221767098072603291                 1
15     -9221674814957667064                 1
16     -9221639938103564513                 1
17     -9221554258551357785                 1
18     -9221307795397202665                 1
19     -9221086586254644858                 1
20     -9221079146476055829                 1
21     -9221066489596332354                 1
22     -9221046405740900422                 1
23     -9221026417907250887                 1
24     -9221015678978880842                 1
25     -9220961720447724253                 1
26     -9220830859283101130                 1
27     -9220733369151052329                 1
28     -9220727250496861488                 1
29     -9220452176650064280                 1
...                     ...               ...
186686  9219686542557325817                 1
186687  9219842210460037807                 1
186688  9219926280825642237                 1
186689  9219937375310355234                 1
186690  9219958455132520777                 1
186691  9220025918063413114                 1
186692  9220160557900894171                 1
186693  9220562120895859549                 1
186694  9220807070557263555                 1
186695  9220814716773471568                 1
186696  9220880169487906579                 1
186697  9220914901466458680                 1
186698  9221114774124234731                 1
186699  9221149157342105139                 1
186700  9221152396628736959                 1
186701  9221297143137682579                 1
186702  9221586026451102237                 1
186703  9221608286127666096                 1
186704  9221693095468078153                 1
186705  9221768426357971629                 1
186706  9221843411551060582                 1
186707  9222110179000857683                 1
186708  9222172248989688166                 1
186709  9222214407720961524                 1
186710  9222355582733155698                 1
186711  9222539910510672930                 1
186712  9222779211060772275                 1
186713  9222784289318287993                 1
186714  9222849349208140841                 1
186715  9223069070668353002                 1

[186716 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have data in memory as a dataframe, you can use:

```
df['device_id'].nunique()
```

otherwise use Gordon's solution - it should be faster

Comment: Some devices come in more than once. That is, line number not = number of devices. But in your solution I get the number of lines.. can this be rightly?

Comment: @harun, no, you will get number of __unique__ devices. If you get the number of rows - then it means you do NOT have any duplicates

Answer (score 2):

If you want the number of different devices, you can just query the database:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct device_id)
FROM phone_brand_device_model ;
```

Of course, if you already have the data in a data frame for some other purpose you can count the number of rows there.

Comment: Some devices come in more than once. That is, line number *not* = number of devices

Comment: @harun . . . Then just use the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in pandas. You can do something like:

```
len(phones.device_id.unique())
```

Comment: Some devices come in more than once. That is, line number not = number of devices. But in your solution I get the number of lines.. can this be rightly?

Comment: @harun I don't think you would get the number of lines with this because of the `unique` function. Are you absolutely sure that the `ids` are not unique if you are getting the same value as the number of lines.

Comment: I used the query with Count and used the method. So the wrong result came out. Was my mistake.